# How could I separate Chess pieces from a string in Scala?

Tags: string, scala, chess

I have information on Chess pieces in string format, for example: `"Ka5Qb3a8b7"`, where `"Ka5"` stands for King in a5, `"Qb3"` for Queen in b3 and `"a8"` for soldier in a8. So if '' then soldier.

How could I separate each piece to bring them later into respective objects? I guess I could loop through each index and match them to different cases and skip 1 or 2 following chars depending if soldier or not. However, I would prefer shorter and more readable code if that kind of approach exists.

I was first thinking to group into sizes of 3 but obviously not possible with soldiers taking only 2 letters. I'm using Scala.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please take the [tour], and read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to make the match a bit more specific listing all the available upper/lowercase chars and digits, where the uppercased chars are in an optional character class `[KQNBR]?` using the questionmark.

```
"[KQNBR]?[a-h][1-8]".r.findAllIn("Ka5Qb3a8b7").toArray
res0: Array[String] = Array(Ka5, Qb3, a8, b7)
```

If the string is always in the same format, using split with lookarounds could also work.

```
"Ka5Qb3a8b7".split("(?<=\\d)(?=[A-Za-z])")
res0: Array[String] = Array(Ka5, Qb3, a8, b7)
```

Answer (score 4):

A regex pattern can do it.

```
"[A-Z]?[a-z]\\d".r.findAllIn("Ka5Qb3a8b7").toList
//res0: List[String] = List(Ka5, Qb3, a8, b7)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Scala 2.13 you can use `List.unfold`:

```scala
val chess = "Ka5Qb3a8b7"
List.unfold(chess) { remainingMoves =>
  Option.when(remainingMoves.nonEmpty) {
    val (currentMove, remaining) = remainingMoves.span(!_.isDigit)
    (currentMove + remaining.head, remaining.tail)
  }
}
```

Result is:

```scala
List(Ka5, Qb3, a8, b7)
```

Code run [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ZuzGKR7dTs6W6RW3IZcUww).